# View how apps look on multiple API levels

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, google-play, android-compatibility

My new *obsession* is to see how specific applications run on different versions of Android. As a beginner I think it's *important* for me to **see how different developers go about releasing their applications for old API levels**.

I downloaded Google I/O 2012 conference app onto my galaxy nexus, and it looks pretty good with the use of the holo theme and all. But how would I go about viewing that app on my 2.3 emulator (I'm really interested how they handle the holo theme on the old version)? I read some other stack overflow posts that it is possible to install an .apk onto an emulator so that is not the problem. I just need to get the `.apk` from the Google Play. Does anyone know if this is possible? Additionally, since my overall goal is to ***see bold text above*** is there another way I should go about this?

The only solution I can think of is to find a friend with a low Android version and tell them to download the app so I can compare. Is there really no better way?

Comment: Where your own apps are concerned, installing on the emulator is usually handled by the build tools, but can be done with the adb install command.  adb install (or even in some cases clicking on a link) also works for apps whose authors have released an APK with the intention of allowing non-Play installs.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that I can install apks onto the emulator with adb. My only problem is acquiring these apks from the play store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how would I go about viewing that app on my 2.3 emulator (I'm really interested how they handle the holo theme on the old version)?

Wait until it is released as open source (reportedly after the conference), then build it and install it on your emulator.

> I just need to get the .apk from the Google Play. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Only by violating copyright.

> Additionally, since my overall goal is to see bold text above is there another way I should go about this?

You could download the source code for other open source applications and build them, such as the [2011 Google I|O conference app](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/).

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know. Thanks once more @CommonsWare. Is there a list of Open Source applications provided by Google?

Comment: @EGHDK: Not that I am aware of, particularly for independent efforts like the I|O conference app.

Comment: How were you able to find iosched? Who actually put that application up, because I'm a little confused... was it not Google?

Comment: @EGHDK: "How were you able to find iosched?" -- I've been monitoring that project since it first came out for the 2010 conference. "Who actually put that application up" -- the Googlers who wrote it. "because I'm a little confused... was it not Google?" -- there is a significant distinction between side projects like the I|O conference app and Google products like Google Maps.